# Can you run in localhost an app that use Twitter OAuth?

Tags: twitter, oauth

When you edit your app settings at Twitter.com, you can asked for a return url, but you can set it to localhost/return. Can you?

I think this is useful in developing time.

When I fill the form with this url: http://localhost/return

I get this error: Not a valid URL format

Comment: Try it and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 37):

http://127.0.0.1/return will do the trick!

Comment: You should accept your own answer to show that this has been solved! (New users keep posting on this post)

Comment: the developer who has written the code for validation should be fired :p

Answer (score 5):

Add `oauth_callback=http://localhost/return` as a parameter when you get request_tokens.

Answer (score 4):

Set your callback url in twitter app setting to `http://127.0.0.1/`.

Comment: I think the OP solved this a long time ago. Please don't post links to your website on old already solved problems, the community will often flag as spam/noise as has happened here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days to resolve this issue you must set callbac url http: //127.0.0.1/
but it dont help me because when i start my application and request tweeter api
it send request at twitter api but respone received on  the for ex: http: //127.0.0.1/:2101 but in my browser url 
http: //localhost/:2101 and twitter api dont understand this,for this you have to manually set the browser URL  http: //127.0.0.1/:2101 if u have same isue.At least for me it was the solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your `hosts` file.

Add something like

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```