# TweetSharp GetRequestToken

Tags: c#, oauth, twitter

I am using TweetSharp Api and I have some problems concerning the service.GetRequestToken().
For example in my Asp.net C# function I do a simple sendTweet().
On my Tweeter account my App is not registered.
So I get an Unauthorized Response and I call my Authorize method.

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService("ConsumerKey", "ConsumerSecret");
OAuthRequestToken requestToken = service.GetRequestToken("callbacklink");
Uri uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
return new RedirectResult(uri.ToString(), false);
```

The problem is that when I'm redirected to the Twitter authorization window the first time I have the good window but if i try again wihtout having authorized my app, the url is like :

> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=?

And I get an error.
If I continue I get the good url and after the empty one and so on...

Do you have any explaination ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nor probleme anymore, I just store the user token in a db and get it at every access.

Answer (score 0):

You problably forget configure the "Callback URL" field on Setting tab of twitter app.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forget configure the "Callback URL" field on Setting tab of twitter app.

Note: localhost will not work, you can use localhost using trick see the details:
[Can you run in localhost an app that use Twitter OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306459/can-you-run-in-localhost-an-app-that-use-twitter-oauth)